# Need help figuring out how to send POST login info in python

Tags: python, http, authentication, python-requests

So I'm currently working on a downloader, and do to so I need to fetch .m3u8 links from webpages that are entered. I've made the program and it works fine, however for premium exclusive videos it can't access the link, because the link doesn't show in the log unless you're logged in. I want to implement the ability to login if you have an account, and I've been using Requests to post the login info along with the authentication key (`_token`) that is required with every login, but to no avail. I log in, then in the `r` variable I try to access a premium exclusive video, yet the link still isn't there. Here's the login section from my code, I've obviously replaced my account details with username and password, but if someone could help me out that'd be much appreciated, I'm still relatively new to python, thanks!

...also, I logged into the website with Fiddler open so I could see what was being posted in an attempt to try and understand the process better, and I've stored that string under 'actual_POST' just for reference.

```
s = requests.Session()

url = "https://roosterteeth.com/login"
payload = {'username': 'password', 'password': 'password', '_token': 'GCZLoBNyjFrN2SReFjEydkN6qx6NT5hU8jVfyZOl'}
actual_POST = '_token=GCZLoBNyjFrN2SReFjEydkN6qx6NT5hU8jVfyZOl&username=username&password=password&redirectTo=http%3A%2F%2Froosterteeth.com%2F'

with s as j:
  b = s.post(url, data=payload, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
  r = s.get('http://roosterteeth.com/episode/rt-sponsor-cut-season-2-sponsor-play-alien-isolation-dlc')
  print(r.text)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a good first question. One thing I noticed is that you're doing `with s as j` and then referencing it with `s`. Try changing that reference to `j`?

Comment: I think `with requests.Session() as s:` would do even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a *_token* you pull from your browswer, you need to make a request and parse the *_token* from the response then use that in the post:

```
import  requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://roosterteeth.com/login"
payload = {'username': 'dyour_user', 'password': 'your_pass',

           "redirectTo":"http://roosterteeth.com/"}
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url)
    payload["_token"] =  BeautifulSoup(r.text).select_one("input[name=_token]")["value"]
    b = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, allow_redirects=1)
    print(BeautifulSoup(b.text,"lxml").select("p.username"))
```

If we run the code above using my login details, you can see we are successful:

```
In [21]: url = "https://roosterteeth.com/login"

In [22]: payload = {'username': 'xxxxx', 'password': 'xxxxx',
   ....: 
   ....:            "redirectTo": "http://roosterteeth.com/"}

In [23]: headers = {
   ....:     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36'}

In [24]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ....:         r = s.get(url)
   ....:         payload["_token"] = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml").select_one("input[name=_token]")["value"]
   ....:         b = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, allow_redirects=1)
   ....:         print(BeautifulSoup(b.text, "lxml").select("p.username"))
   ....:     
[<p class="username"><a href="javascript:void">
                        xxxxx
                                                <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
</a></p>]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works really well, I wasn't aware that the token was pulled from the browser, thought it was just with the site itself